# How to save form info without hash or cookie?

Tags: php, database

I want to save info in a form before a visitor signs up or signs in as a user. The problem is that I'm saving the info in the browser's session, so if the visitor closes his browser after signing up then we loose the form info. Sign up requires email verification, so much of the time the user is likely to close the window and verify his account later. I know another way to do this is using hash, however what should I do in the case of a visitor who already is a user, fills out form, then signs into his account? I can't use a hash in this case and a cookie will not work either.

Comment: Why don't you save the info in your database with the `email_verified` field set as false?

Comment: Any examples of sites that allow filling out form, creating account or signing in, the posting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is that save information into database and generate a confirmation code and send it to the user.

You need `ConfirmationCode` , `Confirmed` database fields to check the user status.

Comment: The way the site is setup, you can fill out the form, then you go to a page to sign up or sign in. If you sign in, then it's posted to your account. If you sign up, then you get an email to verify your email before your account is actually created.

Comment: Try to save information into database anyway. If you want to keep info even closing the browser, It's not true saving form info in cookie or another way. For example, Got the user email address in pre-signin or pre-signup form and save it into database. So you can track the user after signin or signup process with the email address.

Comment: Also you should add a cronjob to delete old form records from the database any 24 hours for example in this way.